# Finding the solution to a tricky integral, where the primitive function is difficult to find

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral

I am stuck at solving this integral, as I can not find the primitive function of the integrand.
Could someone pinpoint me in the right direction?

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \left( \int_{\sqrt[3]{x}}^{1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + y^8}} dy \right) dx$$

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put \left and \right before the parentheses, they expand based on the size of what is inside.  Check it out.

Comment: Isn't any hint given ? Even Fubini (if we can apply it at all in this situation) does not seem to help. Did you try some substitutions ?

Comment: No hint is given, but the answer is ln(1 + sqrt(2))/4

Comment: Maybe you can try to solve it as binomial integral. Some hints about such approach are available at: http://www.nabla.hr/CL-IndefIntegralB5.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of integration is
$$x\in[0,1]\text{ and }\sqrt[3] x\le y\le 1$$

[image]

This is the same as

$$y\in[0,1]\text{ and }0\le x\le y^3$$

So your integral is

$$\int_0^1\left(\int_0^{y^3}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1 + y^8}}\right)dy$$
$$=\int_0^1\frac{y^3}{\sqrt{1 + y^8}}\,dy$$

Now substitute $u=y^4$.